# how I can access file.info in r shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

file.info works on local rstudio but when I deploy on r shiny it does not work. Seems the file information is not accessable to r shiny? is there any other way to capture the file creation date in r shiny.

I am uploading .jpg file (Photo) and I want to make sure the photo is not old one so I am capturing cdate from file.info and comparing with sysdate. It works in local machine but when I deploy on shiny it does not work. It gives NA for all file.info details.

2019-04-20T11:48:25.353489+00:00 shinyapps[841678]:                         size isdir mode mtime ctime atime uid gid uname grname
2019-04-20T11:48:25.353545+00:00 shinyapps[841678]: IMG-20190306-WA0042.jpg   NA    NA         NA  NA     
2019-04-20T11:48:25.354488+00:00 shinyapps[841678]: [1] "2019-04-20"
2019-04-20T11:48:25.355589+00:00 shinyapps[841678]: Warning: Error in if: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
2019-04-20T11:48:25.360865+00:00 shinyapps[841678]:   84: observeEventHandler [/srv/connect/apps/EMPORIOS/app.R#1015]

observeEvent(input$myFile, {
    #df[nrow(intime)+1,] <- NA

```
mfile <- input$myFile
#print(mfile$name)
upload<-    file.info(mfile$name)
print(upload)
filedate<- as.POSIXlt(upload$ctime, tz = "Asia/Kolkata")
filedate<- as.Date(filedate)
print(Sys.Date())
if (filedate !=Sys.Date()) {

shinyalert(
  title = "Old Picture",
  text = "Please upload today's picture",
  closeOnEsc = TRUE,
  closeOnClickOutside = FALSE,
  html = FALSE,
  type = "error",
  showConfirmButton = TRUE,
  showCancelButton = FALSE,
  confirmButtonText = "OK",
  confirmButtonCol = "#AEDEF4",
  timer = 0,
  imageUrl = "",
  animation = TRUE)

  return()
```

}

Comment: Please take time to edit your question properly.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible code snippet